# Unable to get the Sum Property of the WorksheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba

I already tried searching for similar cases but found none.

I am using WorksheetFunction.Sum in my code and works well with most of my files.
but there's a problem when an array has #DIV/0! value.

Here's the code:

```
bool_taskvol = ((Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(taskInputVol, i, 0)) + _
                            Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(taskInputVol_act, i, 0)) + _
                                Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(taskInputVol_hist, i, 0))) = 0)
```

The logic of the code is to return True if the sum of all the row values of the 3 arrays is greater than 0. Unfortunately, there are arrays with #DIV/0! values.

Comment: You need to address the #DIV/0 errors. Try using `IFERROR()` to handle them.

Comment: @bugdrown Where and how should I use IFERROR() in my code? Before creating the array? Or during access of the array?

Comment: I think you meant to tag @bugdrown

Comment: @braX sorry for that. thank you tho :)

Comment: @Christian Balanquit Wrap it around each formula that might yield a `#DIV/0` error.

Comment: Instead of `IFERROR()` you could replace your `SUM()` functions with `AGGREGATE()` and select the options for `SUM` and ignore errors: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aggregate-function-43b9278e-6aa7-4f17-92b6-e19993fa26df